# How to support shortcut pinning in a custom Launcher?

Tags: java, android, android-launcher, homescreen, android-shortcut

I'm making my own Android launcher and I want to react to requests from other apps to add a shortcut to home screen.

So far, I was only able to find out, that apps have to check if shortcut pinning is supported by calling isRequestPinShortcutSupported() from ShortcutManager and then send a request by calling requestPinShortcut() - but how do I implement the other side of that?

I don't know how to tell ShortcutManager my launcher wants to receive these requests and where to handle them. I have tried registering various BroadcastReceivers but that wasn't enough.

Only helpful thing I could find was LauncherApps.PinItemRequest, that can be created from Intent, but I can't find how do I receive this intent.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I had to study android source code for this but I figured out I need to create an Activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.AddShortcutActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PIN_SHORTCUT" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

And then in that Activity's onCreate() I have

```
LauncherApps launcherApps = (LauncherApps)this.getSystemService( Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE);

LauncherApps.PinItemRequest pinItemRequest = launcherApps.getPinItemRequest( intent );

if(pinItemRequest == null)
{
    this.finish();

    return;
}

ShortcutInfo shortcutInfo = pinItemRequest.getShortcutInfo();

boolean exists = false;

//check if shortcut already exists by checking package name and shortcut ID

if( !exists )
{
    pinItemRequest.accept();

    //create your shortcut using shortcutInfo:

    //get icon drawable

    Drawable icon = launcherApps.getShortcutIconDrawable( shortcutInfo, 0 );

    //get label

    String label = "";

    if( shortcutInfo.getShortLabel() != null )
    {
        label = shortcutInfo.getShortLabel().toString();
    }
    else if( shortcutInfo.getLongLabel() != null )
    {
        label = shortcutInfo.getLongLabel().toString();
    }

    //add your shortcut where you need to
}

this.finish();
```

To launch your shortcut, do this:

```
launcherApps.startShortcut( shortcutInfo, null, null );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you maybe remember, cold you add this intent-filter in already created activity? I ask because I use one-activity-app approach.

Comment: No problem. Well... I don't fully understand the Activity system or why would you want only one Activity but I guess if you allow more instances of that one activity and detect what intent it was created with, it could work. If your Activity is single-instance, it's probably going to do something you don't want with the existing instance since you have to handle it in onCreate(). Personally, I don't think that having one extra Activity that closes immediately after it opens (by calling the finish() function) is not that big of a deal even if you insist on one-activity-app approach.

Comment: Do you mind adding some more details about your activity? As LauncherApps() is an unknown method, and adding LauncherApps class doesn't allow getPinItemRequest( this.getIntent() ) directly

Comment: I've updated my original answer.